# Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0 - Error

Tags: angularjs, sequelize.js

I am working on a tutorial for locking down Angular routes (https://catalin.me/role-based-authentication-with-angular-express-jwt-mysql-part-1/) and have run into a error: "Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0". I have read through various documentation on SO and other places on the web but none of the suggestions seem to work for this instance.  Any suggestions?

My code is as follows:

config.js (note the Dialect is here on line 17)

```
// app/config.js

// Application configuration.
'use strict';

var config = module.exports;

config.db = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    name: 'users'
};

config.db.details = {
    host: 'mysaldatabase',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
};

config.keys = {
    secret: '/jVdfUX+u/Kn3qPY4+ahjwQgyV5UhkM5cdh1i2xhozE=' // Not anymore...
};
```

database.js (This is where the new Sequelize comes into play)

```
// app/services/database.js

'use strict';

var config = require('./../config'),
    Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = new Sequelize(
    config.db.id,
    config.db.user,
    config.db.password,
    config.db.email
);
```

user.js

```
// app/models/user.js

// The User model.
"use strict";

var Sequelize = require("sequelize"),
  bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

var config = require("../config"),
  db = require("../services/database");

// 1: The model schema.
var modelDefinition = {
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false
  },

  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
};

// 2: The model options.
var modelOptions = {
  instanceMethods: {
    comparePasswords: comparePasswords
  },
  hooks: {
    beforeValidate: hashPassword
  }
};

// 3: Define the User model.
var UserModel = db.define("user", modelDefinition, modelOptions);

// Compares two passwords.
function comparePasswords(password, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(error, isMatch) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(error);
    }
    return callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}

// Hashes the password for a user object.
function hashPassword(user) {
  if(user.changed('password')) {
      return bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10).then(function(password) {
          user.password = password;
      });
  }
}

module.exports = UserModel;
```

server.js

```
'use strict';

// 1: NPM dependencies.
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// 2: App related modules.
var hookJWTStrategy = require('./services/passportStrategy');


// 3: Initializations.
var app = express();

// 4: Parse as urlencoded and json.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// 5: Hook up the HTTP logger.
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// 6: Hook up Passport.
app.use(passport.initialize());
// Hook the passport JWT strategy.
hookJWTStrategy(passport);

// 7: Set the static files location.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../../public'));

// 8: Home route.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Nice meeting you wizard, I\'m Gandalf!');
});

// 9: Start the server.
app.listen('8080', function() {
    console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:8080/! We are all now doomed!');
});
```

passportStrategy.js

```
'use strict';

// 1: NPM dependencies.
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// 2: App related modules.
var hookJWTStrategy = require('./services/passportStrategy');


// 3: Initializations.
var app = express();

// 4: Parse as urlencoded and json.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// 5: Hook up the HTTP logger.
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// 6: Hook up Passport.
app.use(passport.initialize());
// Hook the passport JWT strategy.
hookJWTStrategy(passport);

// 7: Set the static files location.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../../public'));

// 8: Home route.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Nice meeting you wizard, I\'m Gandalf!');
});

// 9: Start the server.
app.listen('8080', function() {
    console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:8080/! We are all now doomed!');
});
```

Comment: You have `config.db.email` instead of `config.db.details` when you initialize Sequelize.

Comment: Changed the database.js to the following: config.db.id,
    config.db.user,
    config.db.password,
    config.db.email,
    config.db.details ---
    config.db.user,
    config.db.password,
    config.db.details --- Neither seemed to work.

Comment: Check here carefully. https://catalin.me/role-based-authentication-with-angular-express-jwt-mysql-part-1/#the-database-service    
You need 4 arguments in correct order to make it work.